# DocFx: how to create table of contents navigation on site?

Tags: .net, .net-core, docfx

I want to create a table of contents that looks like what [DocFx has on their official site](http://dotnet.github.io/docfx/tutorial/docfx.exe_user_manual.html):

[image]

Using the default `docfx init` command using all of the default values my website looks like this upon build:

[image]\

I've tried tampering with the toc.yml files with no such luck. How do I get this kind of navigation, and for that matter the top-level navigation with DocFx?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out the issue was trying to serve my files locally - security sandboxing prevented some of the JavaScript from running. Worked fine once I used `docfx --serve` instead.